# How to store lat,lng of routed path in Google Map API

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps

I'm developing a web application using PHP and also working with google map API, I want to know that there is anyway to store lat,lng from starting point of path that's been routed to the end point. I've planning to store in MySQL.

Comment: How to store lat/long values in mySQL is a valid question, but your "path" requirement is unclear. Can you show some example data?

Comment: What's with all the arrogance lately?  The question isn't great, but then either flag it, downvote it, and walk away, or make some constructive suggestions. @codingfreak et al

Comment: i know how to store the data but i don't know how to get every lat,lng of routed path.

Comment: you have to loop through the response text from the google API.

Answer (score 0):

For Routes in Google Maps you have two options.

- A) Get the route and save each geo
  point or
- B) Ask the route from Google
  API everytime

So depending on your need, you either need:

- Startpoint and endpoint
- Array of geo points.